# reload nginx with monit

Tags: nginx, monit

I'm looking to reload, not restart, nginx with monit. The docs say that valid service methods are start, stop and restart but not reload.

Does anyone have a workaround for how to reload nginx rather than restart it?

Edit - I should have pointed out that I still require the ability to restart nginx but I also need, under certain conditions, to reload nginx only.

An example might be that if nginx goes down it needs to be restarted but if it has an uptime > 3 days (for example) it should be reloaded.

I'm trying to achieve this: https://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#UPTIME-TESTING

...but with nginx reloading, not restarting.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue using the `exec` command when my conditions are met. For example:

```
check system localhost
  if memory > 95%
  for 4 cycles
  then exec "/etc/init.d/nginx reload"
```

I've found that nginx memory issues can be resolved in the short term by reloading rather than restarting.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the reload signal which should do the job:

```
nginx -s reload
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've edited my question because I hadn't pointed out that I need to reload as well as restart.

Answer (score 0):

"Use the docs. Luke!"

According to the documentation, sending `HUP` signal will cause nginx to re-read its configuration file(s), to check it, and to apply new configuration.

See for details: http://nginx.org/en/docs/control.html#reconfiguration

Comment: Thanks. I think the thing I'm really after is how to enable this in Monit. I know how to reload nginx but not automatically through Monit. I really want to achieve this http://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#PROCESS-UPTIME-TESTING but with reload, not restart. I'll update the question to reflect this.

Comment: It seems that you are asking for wrong advice - reloading nginx is usually done after its config change, while monit is intended to checking nginx's acting\presence. If monit discover nginx failure - you should restart it, not reload its configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a config that will achieve what you wanted:

```
check process nginx with pidfile /usr/local/var/run/nginx.pid
  start program = "/usr/local/bin/nginx -s start"
  stop program = "/usr/local/bin/nginx -s stop"
  if uptime > 3 days then exec "/usr/local/bin/nginx -s reload"
```

I've tried this on my configuration. The only problem I'm seeing is that Monit assumes that you're defining an error condition when checking the uptime like this. The `nginx -s reload` command, as I see it on my machine, does not reset the process' uptime back to 0. Since Monit thinks that the uptime being > 3 days is an error condition being remedied by the command you give it in the config, but that command doesn't reset the uptime to be less than 3 days, Monit will report `Uptime failed` as the status of the process, and you'll see this in the logs:

```
error    : 'nginx' uptime test failed for /usr/local/var/run/nginx.pid -- current uptime is 792808 seconds
```

You'll see hundreds of these, actually (my config has Monit run every 30 seconds, so I get one of these every 30 seconds).

One question: I'm not sure what `reload`ing nginx after a long time, like 3 days, will do for it - is it helpful to do that for nginx? If you have a link to info on why that would be good for nginx to do, that might help other readers getting to this page via search. Maybe you accepted the answer you did because you saw that it would only make sense to do this when there is an issue, like memory usage being high?

(old post, I know, but I got here via Google and saw that the accepted answer was incomplete, and also don't fully understand the OP's intent).

**EDIT**: ah, I see you accepted your own answer. My mistake. So it seems that you did in fact see that it was pointless to do what you initially asked, and instead opted for a memory check! I'll leave my post to give this clarity to any other readers with the same confusion